# How can I echo implode the $result with, and on the same line, without function applied?

Tags: php, echo, implode

How can I echo implode the $result with, and **on the same line**, without function applied?

The code I have so far is:

```
else {

echo implode('<br/>', array_map('convertToBinaryString, $result));

}
```

which produces:

00000
00001
00011

and so on, the NOT binary variants are: 0, 1, 3, etc....

i'd like it to be printed as:

00000 is 0

00001 is 1

00011 is 3

I tried this:

```
echo implode('<br/>', array_map('convertToBinaryString, $result));
echo implode('<br/>', $result);
```

but that produces

00000

00001

00011

...

0

1

3

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like so:

```
foreach ($test as $t)
{ 
    echo $t."\t". bindec($t).'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `convertToBinaryString()` call a new function that concatenates the decimal representation and the binary representation and returns one line of text:

```
$result = [ 0, 1, 3, 6, ];
$output = array_map(
    function ($item) {
        // Use $item to generate one line of output
        return convertToBinaryString($item).' is '.$item;
    },
    $result
);
echo(implode('<br/>', $output));
```

Or you can do it in a plain `foreach` loop way:

```
$result = [ 0, 1, 3, 5 ];
foreach ($result as $item) {
    echo(convertToBinaryString($item).' is '.$item."<br/>");
}
```